# position: absolute causing element to disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wondering if there is any way to fix this issue I am having.

I have three divs, nested in one another

```
<div class="section">
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
Some text.. blah blah. 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I've made the parent's height determined by the child's height with this javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            var $holdme = $(".holdme");
           $holdme.parent().height($holdme.outerHeight());
        });
```

However, this only works when the child element is not positioned absolutely. When I set .child to position:absolute, it causes the parent and the child elements to disappear. Is there any way to set the child to absolute and make the parent container's height change to fit the child's height?

Here is a fiddle... right now it is working correctly but the absolute positioning is not set for the child element. Deleting the comment markup from around position:absolute breaks everything.

http://jsfiddle.net/jjalbert/dHt7L/3/

Comment: of course you're all right, that was a silly mistake. Unfortunately I am still having the issue in the actual code... I just thought I recreated the problem in the fiddle but instead I just made a new problem by forgetting to change that class :P

Comment: Probably best to leave this question as it is, figure out how to reproduce the issue, and ask another question with an updated fiddle. If I see the new version, I'll try to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML doesn't use the `holdme` class, and your fiddle wasn't importing jQuery. [Correcting both of these makes it work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/XktGN/):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         var $holdme = $(".child");
        $holdme.parent().height($holdme.outerHeight());
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `.holdme` class applied anywhere...

Should that be `.chlid` ?

```
var $holdme = $(".child");
```

It works as you want if you make this change..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/dHt7L/8/

Answer (score 1):

Heres a fiddle of a working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/dHt7L/10/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         var $holdme = $(".child");
        $holdme.parent().height($holdme.outerHeight());
     });
```

​

I removed your overflow: rules.. not sure if it was important, but part of my workflow